# Functor right adjoint to $.\otimes_BA$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products, adjoint-functors

Given a ring morphism from $B$ to $A$, we can regard an $A$-module $M$ as a $B$-module. Then how can I prove the functor $._B:\operatorname{Mod}_A \to \operatorname{Mod}_B$ is right adjoint to $.\otimes_BA$, i.e., $\operatorname{Hom}_A(N\otimes A, M)\cong  \operatorname{Hom}_B(N,M_B)$?

I guess this is some kind of standard result, so where can I find some reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the standard adjunction with the Hom functor, namely
$$
M_B\cong\operatorname{Hom}_A(A,M)
$$
regarding $A$ as a $B$-module by means of the given homomorphism.

Another way to see this is by building the natural bijection by hand. If $f\colon N\otimes_BA\to M_B$ is a homomorphism of $B$-modules, define $\tilde{f}\colon N\to M$ by $\tilde{f}(x)=f(x\otimes 1)$. Prove this is a homomorphism of $B$-modules.

The inverse map sends $g\colon N\to M_B$ to $\hat{g}$ defined via the $B$-balanced map $\bar{g}\colon N\times A\to M$ by
$$
\bar{g}(x,a)=g(x)a
$$

Comment: I am sorry, could you please explain a little bit more why $M_b \cong Hom_A(A,M)?

Comment: To see his proposed module isomorphism you should first check that there is a module/linear bijection between $M$ and $\text{Hom}_A(A,M)$. To do this you need to rely on the fact that a $A$-module homomorphism $A \to M$ is completely determined by where it sends $1 \in A$, here I'm assuming all rings are commutative with unit. From there you just apply the same $B$-module structure on $\text{Hom}_A(A,M)$ as you would $M$, under the bijection, to get $M_B \cong \text{Hom}_A(A,M)$.

Comment: @Learning As already commented, you just need to consider $f\mapsto f(1)$ for getting the homomorphism $\mathrm{Hom}_A(A,M)$; the converse is sending $x$ to the map $a\mapsto xa$.